# Window for a newly started process in C# is showing up behind my current open windows

Tags: c#, .net

I have some fairly straightforward code to open up files using a Process object:

```
        var proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = attachmentPath;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        proc.Start();
```

Every once in a while, the window that opens from this process starting open behind all my currently open windows.  I don't see any pattern or consistency to why this happens.  Does anybody have an idea why this happens, or how I can work around it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows has discouraged applications from stealing focus for a while; the rules around it aren't really documented, presumably to prevent applications from working around them.

However, you could give this a try:

```
    var proc = new Process();
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = attachmentPath;
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    proc.Start();

    //Wait for window to spin up
    proc.WaitForInputIdle();
    BringWindowToTop(proc.MainWindowHandle);
```

Define [BringWindowToTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632673(VS.85).aspx) with [p/invoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.BringWindowToTop).

Comment: The rules for being able to set focus are documented.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632668%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: That's for SetForegroundWindow, not so much for a new process's window.  That being said, good link which shows what Microsoft is aiming for.